# JQuery validation of non numeric field

Tags: jquery, validation

How do I validate a field to have only non numeric characters? 
I have a field for first name, which can only Use a-z A-Z and allow '-', whitespace between characters.
I tried using
firstName: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 2,
    maxlength: 32,
    digits: false
},

But the digits rule just doesn't work when it's set to false

Comment: Are you trying to prevent a user from entering numbers or is this a form that needs validation upon submit?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the input masked so that they can't enter numbers at all, you can use this jQuery plugin http://hdserv.me/jQuery/Samples/jQuery%20AlphaNumeric.html. Then you can use

```
$('.sample3').alpha()
```

You can set the `allow` property to allow '-'. There are a bunch of examples on the site

Comment: Wow, did not know about this plugin. Could come in handy. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `filter` function to filter out all of your inputs with values that don't match any regex. In the example below, I've added a class ('my-error-class') to all of the inputs that didn't match. You could do anything here. Also, I'm no regex pro, so I don't know if the dash inside the brackets needs to be escaped.

```
$('.some-inputs')
    .filter(function(index) {
        return !this.value.match(/[a-zA-Z\-\s]+/);
    })
    .addClass('my-error-class');
```